# How can I setup Nginx with a transparent socket?

Tags: linux, nginx, networking, linux-networking, transparent-proxy

Similarly to [this](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-we-built-spectrum/) Cloudflare blog post, I am trying to setup Nginx with a transparent socket (with the [`IP_TRANSPARENT` socket option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)). I want to do this to implement a reverse TCP proxy that effectively binds to all ports.

The `IP_TRANSPARENT` socket option is [not natively supported](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/287) by Nginx for listening so I am trying to create the socket using a [Systemd socket unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) and then pass it to the Nginx process using the [`NGINX` environment variable](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/pull/703).

The socket unit is as follows (unimportant lines have been removed):

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=127.0.0.1:1234
Transparent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

My Nginx service unit is as follows (unimportant lines have been removed):

```
[Service]
# Configure Nginx to use the socket inherited from Systemd
Environment=NGINX=3;
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And my `nginx.conf` is as follows (unimportant lines have been removed and `upstream` is the hostname of the upstream host I want to proxy to):

```
stream {
    server {
        proxy_pass upstream:443
        listen 127.0.0.1:1234;
    }
}
```

Nginx is running on a GCP compute instance behind an [internal passthrough load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal) with IP address 10.11.12.13 so I have added the following iptables rule to redirect traffic to the transparent socket:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -d 10.11.12.13/32 -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port=1234 --on-ip=127.0.0.1
```

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal#how_ilb_works), GCP installs the local route for the load balancer, so there is no need to do that myself. In other words, the following command returns `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`:

```
ip route add local 10.11.12.13/32 dev lo src 127.0.0.1
```

However, the following curl command hangs:

```
curl https://10.11.12.13
```

The TCP connection is being established correctly from the perspective of curl, however when stracing the Nginx worker process it seems to be hanging on the `accept4` system call.

Running `tcpdump` from the instance that Nginx is running on shows the following:

```
15.59.51.564902 IP [REDACTED].50028 > 10.11.12.13.443: Flags [S], seq 3519046460, win 65535, options [mss 1320,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3905128064 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
15.59.51.564973 IP 10.11.12.13.443 > [REDACTED].50028: Flags [S.], seq 2512605282, ack 3519046461, win 28400, options [mss 1420,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15.59.51.601898 IP [REDACTED].50028 > 10.11.12.13.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 4096, length 0
15.59.51.601898 IP [REDACTED].50028 > 10.11.12.13.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:370, ack 1, win 4096, length 369
15.59.51.601898 IP 10.11.12.13.443 > [REDACTED].50028: Flags [.], ack 370, win 231, length 0
```

As I understand, this means that the client is sending data, the server is acknowledging it, but then the client is not sending any more data, presumably because it's expecting a response from the server that it is not receiving. For this reason, I suspect Nginx is just ignoring the data sent by the client.

I hope I have provided enough context to understand the problem. I am not too sure where to go from here or if there is something fundamentally wrong with what I am trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787180/6180803) which was to set the following option on the Nginx service unit:

```
[Service]
NonBlocking=true
```

Presumably Nginx assumes that this option is set when the listening socket is created so data cannot be read if Systemd passes it a socket without this option set.